# how to parse Json array that has above hundreads of arrays and its multiple objects

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i am beginner at android can anybody tell me how to parse All Json arrays that come under one fix array i want to parse all array name in parents

Following is the sample Json:

```
{
  "err-code": 0,
  "worksheet": [
    {
      "2016-08-19": [
        {
          "worksheet_id": 130,
          "job_no": "ES100353-AF",
          "message": "Matthew Smith has submitted Worksheet for Approval",
          "added_date": "19 Aug 2016",
          "added_time": "06:31 AM",
          "status": "Pending"
        }
      ],
      "2016-08-18": [
        {
          "worksheet_id": 107,
          "job_no": "ES100353-AF",
          "message": "Matthew Smith has submitted Worksheet for Approval",
          "added_date": "18 Aug 2016",
          "added_time": "05:31 AM",
          "status": "Pending"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you need to create a pojo class for your jsonObject, Afterward my library handles it automatically, Try it once https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Comment: please post some part of your JSON, so i can help you.

Comment: i have posted .u may see brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the JSON using Android's native JSON parser as below:

```
public ParsedData parseWorksheet(String in) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
        String errCode = reader.getString("err-code");
        JSONArray jsonArrayOuter = reader.optJSONArray("worksheet");
        ParsedData parsedData = new ParsedData();
        parsedData.errCode = errCode;
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArrayOuter.length(); i++){
          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayOuter.getJSONObject(i);
          Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
          ArrayList<Worksheet> worksheetArrayList = new ArrayList<Worksheet>();
          while(iterator.hasNext()){
              Worksheet worksheet= new Worksheet();
               String key = (String)iterator.next();
               worksheet.worksheetDataKey = key;
               JSONArray jsonArrayW =  jsonObject.optJSONArray(key);
               WorksheetInnerData[] WorksheetDataArray = new WorksheetInnerData[jsonArrayW.length()];
               for(int j=0; j < jsonArrayW.length(); j++){
                  JSONObject jsonObjectWorksheetData = jsonArrayW.getJSONObject(j);
                  WorksheetInnerData worksheetData= new WorksheetInnerData();
                  String worksheet_id = jsonObjectWorksheetData.getString("worksheet_id");
                  worksheetData.worksheet_id = worksheet_id;
                  String job_no = jsonObjectWorksheetData.getString("job_no");
                  worksheetData.job_no = job_no;
                  String message = jsonObjectWorksheetData.getString("message");
                  worksheetData.message = message;
                  String added_date =  jsonObjectWorksheetData.getString("added_date");
                  worksheetData.added_date = added_date;
                  String status = jsonObjectWorksheetData.getString("status");
                  worksheetData.status = status;
                  WorksheetDataArray[j] = worksheetData;
               }
               worksheet.WorksheetInnerDataArray = WorksheetDataArray;
               worksheetArrayList.add(worksheet);
           }
          parsedData.worksheetArray = worksheetArrayList;
       }
      return parsedData ;
    }
```

Following should be your data model:

```
private static class ParsedData {
    public String errCode;
    public ArrayList<Worksheet> worksheetArray;
}

private static class Worksheet {
    public String worksheetDataKey;
    public WorksheetInnerData WorksheetInnerDataArray [];
}

private static class WorksheetInnerData {
    public String worksheet_id;
    public String job_no;
    public String message;
    public String added_date;
    public String status;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: arrays name are not fixed its a lot ..means everyday array name increase according to date..so in this case how to parse nested array ..means they are not static

Comment: u may see array names are date

Comment: brother its array under array..top array is worksheet and they have also array "2016-08-19" and now they have objects..see my code

Comment: brother using your code .i could not entered into arrays of array..i have posted  my code ..you may see

Comment: please post your complete JSON

Comment: i already posted see properly brother...and see arrays within array also...

Comment: @chandeshwarThakur i have added fresh code, and also tested it, it's parsing correctly now, check.

Comment: @chandeshwarThakur just copy and paste the code it should work for you now.

Comment: i cant vote..beacuse my reputation is below 15..so i need reputation thn ican dot that

Answer (score 1):

its very simple to parse json data to file,
1).you need first String object if it true

2)then take JsonArray with its object to get  "worksheet" array
the
3).now your question is :you have huge json arrays
  then a).take Iterator for get all array keys by Iterator
        and save it to arraylist.
       b).and string object pass it to the JSONArray(Stringkey);
       c)now get all strings within json array using loop
       d)and save all to ..where you want to save
    finish..

this is the way you can parse eaisly

Comment: Wow you just did commentary of my answer... LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try This

         RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); 
       final String url = "http://httpbin.org/get?param1=hello";

    //prepare the Request
   JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
  JSONArray responserecentbooks = response.getJSONArray("arrayname");
                for (int i = 0; i < responserecentbooks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) responserecentbooks.get(i);
                    String bookid = person.getString("element");
                   //store values in Arraylist 
                    try {

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
        Log.d("Error.Response", response);
   }
}
);

 // add it to the RequestQueue   
 queue.add(getRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' at app level build.gradle.
2. Create same class structure like JSON
3. new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken>() {
                   }.getType());